# Parameters for onclick function

Tags: javascript, raphael

Drawing a set of circle with RaphaelJS library.

For each circle I want to create an `onclick` function that passes a variable, but in this function my variable is undefined.

What is the problem?

This is my code:

```
//children is an array such as [1,2,4[5,6,7]]
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var array = children;
    alert("ARRAY[0]===" + array[0])

    var st = space2Draw.set();
    st.push(space2Draw.circle(xChildren, yChildren, 20).click(function (array) {
        //array[i] is undefined
        alert("ARRAY[i]===" + array[i]);
        //retrive(array[i]);
    }),
    LineRoot(xRadice, yRadice, xChildren, yChildren, space2Draw));
    space2Draw.text(xChildren, yChildren, children[i]).attr({
        fill: "white"
    });
    st.attr({
        fill: "red"
    });

    xChildren += 50;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this:

```
...
st.push(space2Draw.circle(xChildren, yChildren, 20).click((function (array, i) {
    return function () {
        //array[i] is undefined
        alert("ARRAY[i]===" + array[i]);
        //retrive(array[i]);
    }
}(array, i)));
...
```

The reason why this works is that in javascript, scope is defined by functions, not by blocks.

Your callback gets access (by closure) to the `array` and `i` (among other variables), but when the callback gets executed, `i` is equal to `children.length`, because the loop has finished iterating.

By using IIFE (immediately invocation function expression) we create a new scope, and the callback gets access to the *current* value of `array` and `i`.

---

Also, the `click` function calls the callback by passing an `event` object as first parameter, so our IIFE should return this

```
return function (event) {
    // access array and i by closure
    // event is the event representing the click
    // event, provided by Raphael

    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a "array" parameter to your click callback, it is overriding the "array" var from the parent scope. You can just remove the argument and it should be ok.

I think you will have another problem with i always being children.length in your click callback (because the function scope will actually be closed at the end of the loop. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)). You should create an auxiliary function to create the callback for you.

You could try something like this:

```
//children is an array such as [1,2,4[5,6,7]]
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var array = children;
    alert("ARRAY[0]===" + array[0])

    var st = space2Draw.set();
    st.push(space2Draw.circle(xChildren, yChildren, 20).click(getCallback(array , i)),
    LineRoot(xRadice, yRadice, xChildren, yChildren, space2Draw));
    space2Draw.text(xChildren, yChildren, children[i]).attr({
        fill: "white"
    });
    st.attr({
        fill: "red"
    });

    xChildren += 50;
}

function getCallback(array , i){
   return function () {
        alert("ARRAY[i]===" + array[i]);
    }
}
```